# $ x^{2} - 2px -5q = (x-m)(x-n)$ and $ x^{2} - 2mx -5n = (x-p)(x-q)$ What is $p+q+m+n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, quadratics

It is known that
$$ x^{2} - 2px -5q = (x-m)(x-n)$$
and
$$ x^{2} - 2mx -5n = (x-p)(x-q)$$

with $p \ne q \ne m \ne n$. What is $p+q+m+n$?

---

***Attempt:***

We get that 
$$ m+n = 2p, \:\:\: mn = -5q $$
$$ p +q = 2m, \:\: pq = -5n $$

We can get that 
$$ (m+n)(p+q) = 100 $$
from $ m  + n = 2 (-5n/q) $ and $ p +q = 2(-5q/n) $.

So $$ ((p + q) + (m + n))^{2} = (m+n)^{2} + (p+q)^{2} + 200$$

We also can get $n+q = m + p$. So

$$ ((n + q) + (m + p))^{2} =  4 (m+p)^{2} = 4 (n+q)^{2}$$

How to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to solve the following system:
$$m+n=2p,$$
$$p+q=2m,$$
$$mn=-5q$$ and
$$pq=-5m.$$
Since $n=2p-m$ and $q=2m-p,$ we obtain:
$$m(2p-m)=-5(2m-p)$$ and
$$p(2m-p)=-5(2p-m),$$ which gives
$$m(2p-m)-p(2m-p)=-5(2m-p)+5(2p-m)$$ or
$$p^2-m^2=15p-15m$$ or
$$(p-m)(p+m-15)=0.$$
Can you end it now?